# secure ftp to specific directory on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, file-transfer, scp

can I set up

- a secure ftp for somebody (not a current user on the system)
- for 2 different directories on Ubuntu
- inside public_html?

I don't want to give the user pure ssh account right now.

Any other upload,download,delete file secure way is good too. **nginx** is available not apache2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using `scponly`

**Edit:**

Example set-up:

1) create account for using `scponly`:

```
sudo useradd joe
```

2) change default shell for the account:

```
sudo chsh joe
```

answer with `/usr/bin/scponly`, (make sure that `/usr/bin/scponly` is in `/etc/shells`)

3) you can modify joe's home directory to `/my/web/site/dir` in `/etc/passwd`

```
sudo vim /etc/passwd
```

4) modify permissions:

```
sudo chgrp -R joe /my/web/site/dir
sudo chmod -R g+w /my/web/site/dir
```

5) If you are using `AllowUsers` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` add joe to the list
of users that can log in.

6) restart ssh:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

7) test from another host:

```
scp web_site_stuff.html joe@site.com:
```

Comment: @Casual Coder: I like scponly but I am not sure how I can handle the permissions. I want to give access to the installation of Wordpress but I guess I cannot change the permission from www-data to something else. So should I add this new user to www-data group?

Comment: You can create for instance scp group, change your scp-accessible dir owner:group to `www-data:scp`, and grant write permssions to scp group.

Comment: would the web server work ok if I change the group permission from www-data?

Comment: user `www-data` is still the owner of the dir and has appropriate permissions. Only group have changed.

Comment: Of course you can go with `www-data` group with write permission and add scpuser (in an example joe) to `www-data` group, but in my opinion it would be less secure.

Comment: and this is what confuses me ...

Comment: `www-data` user(and group) is account under which your web server is running. So granting write access to that user/group should be considered carefully. Of course in cases like setting up WebDAV access, or uploading files you need to grant write access to `www-data`, but you are securing system in other ways.(in case of WebDAV: TLS + authentication; in case of uploads: separate directory outside of public path).

Comment: ok, but how can I grant access to only two websites sitting inside /srv/www not to all of them?

Answer (score 1):

I beleive that you could use rssh to setup a restricted shell to provide access over sftp but not over say ssh. I also beleive that you could "lock" the user to specific folders by using chroot.
Here are two links that explains this further:

[How to: Restrict Users to SCP and SFTP and Block SSH Shell Access with rssh](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-centos-linux-install-configure-rssh-shell.html)

[Linux Configure rssh Chroot Jail To Lock Users To Their Home Directories Only](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-rssh-chroot-jail-setup.html)

Please note that I have actually never done this myself.

*Edit: As Zoredache points out it may be a better solution to do the chrooting in the sshd config direcly, instead of doing this in the rssh config as the above link suggests.*

Comment: cool, I'll have a look when I get home!

Comment: Those documents almost certainly should not be used for recent versions of SSH which have a built in method for an [sftp chroot](http://serverfault.com/search?q=chroot+sftp).

Comment: yep, looks like an better solution to setup the chroot in sshd_config directly.

Comment: Avada - that kind of counts as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Make one home directory for new user then
symlink other two dir. in that home dir & give that two folder appropriate permission.

Answer (score 1):

finally I use [Limiting Access with SFTP Jails on Debian and Ubuntu](http://library.linode.com/security/sftp-jails/)

Comment: Looks like a nice explanation but it does not work for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

at the end I used [pure-FTPd with TLS support](http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README.TLS)